# Call OnTriggerEnter Twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm coding a 2D platformer in Unity and need to call the OnTriggerEnter function twice, I've created one Public Collider2D, named headPos,
the first time I use the OnTriggerEnter2D is here

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D headPos)
{
 //Run My Code
{
```

And the second time I use it is here

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
 //Run More Code
{
```

I get the following error

```
Type 'Player' already defines a member called 'OnTriggerEnter2D' with the same parameter types
```

How do I check for two seperate OnTriggerEnter2D's?

Comment: You can't define the-same function twice. Why are you doing this? Why do want that to be called twice?

Comment: The first time I need an entirely different trigger to be detected and the second time I need a different trigger to be detected.

Comment: That doesn't make sense....You want to detect multiple gameobjects that is marked as trigger?

Comment: At the start of the game I use the OnTriggerEnter function in the game's Intro, and I also need to use it for a game mechanic where the player crawls so that if the trigger (positioned where his head would be) is activated the player can't stand up.

Comment: @MountainSideStudios - What does "different trigger to be detected" mean?

Comment: I've got one trigger at the start of the game

Comment: and one constantly on the players head

Comment: @MountainSideStudios - Are those the answer to my question?

Comment: @MountainSideStudios - What does "different trigger to be detected" mean?

Comment: At the start of the game I detect the first trigger and then for the rest of the game I'm just detecting the head trigger

Comment: @Enigmativity above is some info thanks for helping

Comment: @MountainSideStudios - I don't think you're following me. I don't understand what the words "different trigger to be detected" mean? Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: @MountainSideStudios You question is confusing. Anyways check my answer and see if that's what you want to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say different triggers, it looks like you are trying to detect different gameobjects with trigger. If this this is true, then you can use `if` statement to check which gameobject was triggered.

You can `tag` each body part with collider/trigger and detect with code like below:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if(col.CompareTag("head")){
        //Run My Code
        Debug.Log("Head Triggered!");
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("hand"))
    {
        //Run My Code
        Debug.Log("Hand Triggered!");
    }
    else if (col.CompareTag("leg"))
    {
        //Run My Code
        Debug.Log("Leg Triggered!");
    }
}
```

You can also compare them by name

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
 {

     if (col.name == "head")
     {
         //Run My Code
         Debug.Log("Head Triggered!");
     }
     else if (col.name == "hand")
     {
         //Run My Code
         Debug.Log("Hand Triggered!");
     }
     else if (col.name == "leg")
     {
         //Run My Code
         Debug.Log("Leg Triggered!");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the use case? You should never use the same function twice, especially when it comes to optimization.

I guess what you want to achieve is detecting two separate collisions happening in the same time. In this case your function OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D headPos) will be called twice with different colliding object passed in every time.